# How to create a custom UIButton (with images) but still use setTitle?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, background-image

I've tried creating a UIButton with UIButtonTypeCustom. Then afterwards used the following methods to adjust the look of it

```
[sendButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sendButtonOff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sendButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sendButtonOn.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];      
[sendButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sendButtonDisabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

However the problem is, once you start setting UIImages to the states, setTitle no longer works. I think setTitle only works with non-UIButtonTypeCustom? This means I either have to put the text into the images themselves (not very robust) or subclass this and add a UILabel to the view? Sounds like alot of work :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the title to display over the image, try using this:

```
[sendButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sendButtonOff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sendButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sendButtonOn.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];      
[sendButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sendButtonDisabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```