# Using the State design pattern in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, state-pattern

I'm new to Objective-C and I'm learning OOP design patterns, but I'm an experienced functional programmer. I believe I need to use the State design pattern to implement my button, but I'm not sure what the best way to do it is.

Presently, the button has three states: `ACTIVE`, `INACTIVE`, and `FINISHED`. Depending on which state the button is in, it will be drawn in a different way. Instead of using a `switch` or subclassing the button for each state, my plan was to use three different categories, each overwriting the `drawRect:` method in `MyButton`. However, after looking around, I've discovered that this is highly discouraged.

What is the best way to tackle this? Should I subclass the button, use a category or a delegate, or is there another solution that I'm not thinking of?

EDIT: I should add that while I'm not building a game, I am basing my State pattern off of the explanation [here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html).

Comment: If you mean *Objective-C category feature*, then you shouldn't use it to override a method. Objective-C is very old language and you need to think in C way. Category methods is applied globally, and doesn't support contextual application.

Comment: I suspect you're overthinking this.  You've not explained why using the built-in button state would not work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on how you are trying to change the appearance of the button.  If you can get what you want by setting the image or other standard attributes for the button, then I would leave the button class alone and just configure it from an external view model class.  Let the button be responsible for managing the [UIControlState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlState) and configure it from your view controller or from a separate view model class.

If you need to drastically change the appearance of the button, then subclassing and providing your own drawRect: is the proper approach, although even there I would consider defining the class to have the minimal code needed to handle you different rendering needs and keep the state machine outside of the button.  Conceptually the button should be responsible for drawing itself and detecting user events, more complicated application logic should be handled by a delegate class.  Keep your UI components simple and reusable.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I have a distinction between the button's visual state -- `ACTIVE`,`FINISHED`, etc. -- and the state in the UI. If the button is `ACTIVE` then it can be tapped, otherwise it can't be, and the state flags exist to change how the button appears.

Comment: Sorry, I realized when I saw your edit.  I've updated my answer to reflect this use case.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I do need a fairly drastic appearance change, so I'll keep my current subclass but handle appearance state changes in separate MyButtonInterface class, which will be a delegate of the subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Consider delegate (by protocol) as a first option. Because delegate provides you a loosely coupled, flexible way to customize behaviors. (delegate = observer pattern) Anyway this is often feels too verbose.

Consider subclassing-and-overriding only when you *have to*. Subclassing/overriding is a powerful construct, and it 's very fragile like other too powerful construct. Because you need to properly handle calling of superclass method not to break the feature. Then it should be used very carefully. (recent compiler may warn on some cases) Unfortunately many Cocoa features are based on subclassing, then subclassing often becomes the only option. In this case, you're using `UIView` class, and `UIView` class does not support customizing drawing behavior by delegate, then you have to use subclassing with proper state value.

Never consider category to *override* a method. The feature is not intended for overriding, and actually implicit and silent overriding of existing method is one of the issue of category. (now you will be warned by the compiler in some cases)

You have another way called *Objective-C blocks* instead of delegate pattern which is an Objective-C version of closures. Blocks can replace delegate and target-action pattern in many cases, but  sometimes discouraged because its implicit capturing behavior may cause memory management issue.

#### Optimization

Though `drawRect:` is enough to provide custom look of a button, drawing is very expensive operation, and you need to avoid it as much as possible. If your button has a static look, then it would be better to use a bitmap image. `UIButton` already have methods to support this.

Not only for `UIButton`, many UIKit classes provides [built-in look customization features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123110/how-to-create-a-custom-uibutton-with-images-but-still-use-settitle), and I recommend you to consider using of the built-in features primarily.

And then, how to run a code for a specific state? `UIButton` already have a feature for that. Its superclass [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) has a built-in method called `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` and you can use this to register an observer method. This is an analogue to the delegate pattern, then it's more robust. Also, this is designed, and intended way to handle button behavior. Many stuffs in Cocoa are predefined like this, and you might need to spend some time to look for existing design intentions.

#### Consistency

These features are baked into the button class, and less flexible then providing your own drawing implementation by implementing your own state pattern/machine. But strongly recommended because this is the only way to provide semantically/practically *exact behavior* of typical system-default iOS app behavior.

Comment: So instead of using `drawRect:` your suggestion is to use a method more like what penguinmaster suggested below, but instead of subclassing `UIButton`, I should handle all the logic and view from an external class?

Comment: @AFL, if you don't want a fully custom look, then you don't have to subclass the `UIButton` class. Because it provides an observer for state change. I updated my answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite the drawRect: in the button state then subclass will be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass a UIButton and create a new method to handle this. For example, you might call your subclass MYButton and put a new method called:

> -(void) setButtonState: (NSInteger) state;

In it, you would want to do something like:

> -(void) setButtonState: (NSInteger) state {
>
> > switch (state) {
> >
> > > case ACTIVE:
> > >
> > > > //Do ACTIVE CHANGES and so on like [self setImage: forState:] if you want to change the image, etc.
>
> }